# How do I solve this Matrice/Vectors question?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Give the matrix for the following linear operator:
$A \vec{x} = (3,2,6) \times \vec{x}$,
where $\vec{x}$ is any arbitrary vector.

Comment: Start off by computing $(3,2,6)\times (a,b,c)$.  Can you do that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Yes, I can do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T,$ then we know $$(3,2,6)^T\times \vec{x} =(-6 x_2 + 2 x_3, 6 x_1 - 3 x_3, -2 x_1 + 3 x_2)^T$$
So we can see that $$A(1,0,0)^T=(0,6,-2)^T$$
$$A(0,1,0)^T=(-6,0,3)^T$$
$$A(0,0,1)^T=(2,-3,0)^T$$
So these must constitute the columns of $A,$ so $A=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -6 & 2\\
6& 0 & -3\\
-2 & 3 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$

(We need to use the transpose since matrices, conventionally, don't act on row vectors).